# Mobile : PhoneGap/Adobe AIR : how to list all active network devices

Tags: android, networking, mobile, air, cordova

I would like to create a mobile app where you can see (and select) the other devices in a network.

My question is: is it possible to list all active devices within a network (either by IP-adress or networkname)?

I am trying to do this in Adobe AIR AND/OR PhoneGap.